# problem with php: read filenames, generate javascript and html

Tags: php, javascript, html, file, directory

### **UPDATE**

Hello again. I found myself with a new problem. The php code worked perfectly on my PC (wamp server) but i've now uploaded it on a free webhost server and while the php part runs perfectly (it produces the array) the javascript function itself doesn't work cause there are no photos in the website when it's loaded. I tried to test it by putting in the function's first line an alert to see if it runs but never showed up. I think that the server for some reason doesn't realise that it is a javascript function because i also had in the getphotos.php this:

```
window.onload = photos();
```

which appart from starting the photos function, shows a text. When i moved that line in js file and put the show text line first, it run showing the text but still no photos. What do you think????

**END OF UPDATE**

---

Hello to everyone. I am building a website that shows some photos. I want the site to automatically generate the html code that shows the photos by reading the file names in the photo folder, but i need also to use javascript. So I found through the web a solution with php generating javascript which than generates the html code I want and I think this is what I need. But... it doesn't work X_X. So I need someone's help!

Firstly, here is the php/javascript(in getPhotos.php):

```
<?
header("content-type: text/javascript");

//This function gets the file names of all images in the current directory
//and ouputs them as a JavaScript array
function returnImages() {
    $pattern="(*.jpg)|(*.png)|(*.jpeg)|(*.gif)"; //valid image extensions
    $files = array();
    $curimage=0;
    if($handle = opendir('/photos/')) {
        while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
            if(eregi($pattern, $file)){ //if this file is a valid image
                //Output it as a JavaScript array element
                echo 'galleryArray['.$curimage.']="'.$file .'";';
                $curimage++;
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    return($files);
}

//here starts the javascript function
echo 'window.onload = photos;
    function photos(){
    var i;
    var text1 = "";
    var text2 = "";
    var text3 = "";
    var galleryArray=new Array();'; //Define array in JavaScript
returnImages(); //Output the array elements containing the image file names

//short the images in three sets depending on their names and produce the code
echo 'for(i=0; i<galleryArray.length; i++){
    if(galleryArray[i].indexOf("set1_")!=-1){
        text1+= "<a rel=\"gallery\" title=\"\" href=\"photos/"+galleryArray[i]+"\">\n<img alt=\"\" src=\"photos/"+galleryArray[i]+"\" />\n</a>\n" ;
    }else if(galleryArray[i].indexOf("set2_")!=-1){
        text2+= "<a rel=\"gallery\" title=\"\" href=\"photos/"+galleryArray[i]+"\">\n<img alt=\"\" src=\"photos/"+galleryArray[i]+"\" />\n</a>\n" ;
    }else if(galleryArray[i].indexOf("set3_")!=-1){
        text3+= "<a rel=\"gallery\" title=\"\" href=\"photos/"+galleryArray[i]+"\">\n<img alt=\"\" src=\"photos/"+galleryArray[i]+"\" />\n</a>\n" ;
    }
}';

//create text nodes and put them in the correct div
echo 'var code1 = document.createTextNode(text1);
    var code2 = document.createTextNode(text2);
    var code3 = document.createTextNode(text3);
    document.getElementById("galleryBox1").appendChild(code1);
    document.getElementById("galleryBox2").appendChild(code2);
    document.getElementById("galleryBox3").appendChild(code3);
}';

?>
```

And this is the code in the mane page index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="getPhotos.php"></script><!--get photos from dir-->
```

This is it, and it doesn't work! I know I ask to much by just giving all the code and asking for help but i can't even think what's wrong, let alone how to fix it.... So please, if you have any idea it would be great.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", you need to be a little more specific. Does the page produce any output? If so, then where does it get to before it stops? If you see only a blank page, then that indicates a syntax error somewhere.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "doesn't work"? Is your galleryArray empty or are text1, text2, text3 empty?

Comment: You can also make sure that PHP is showing all errors by including [these lines of code](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/1718).

Comment: @strauberry Great minds and all that!

Comment: i want an answer without making the wright question....X_X sorry =) When I say doesn't I mean it produces nothing at all! Viewing the page source after i run it in a server and I can stil see all the php code (i think i shouldn't be able to see it) as i gave it above and no results. i have put in the folder photos with the wright name but it returns nothing. It's like it doesn't run at all.

Comment: Try replacing the first line with `<?php`. Maybe your cgi module does not recognize short tags.

Comment: @Thomas I think that's it. Cause I don't see the php code anymore. Stil it doesn't give filename in javascript because it says error didn't find the folder but changing this might work. Thanx

Comment: What does it currently output? Have a look in the 'net' panel of Firebug. BTW, it's generally *not* a good idea to `echo` all those texts to the browser. PHP is a templating language, it is really a better practice to output large chunks of HTML and/or JavaScript by closing and reopening the PHP code, like `?>var i = []; /* etc. */<?php`

Comment: the output is wright... it seems like a perfectly good working javascript function.... Basically its exactly the same as the output of the page i run on my pc which works fine.

Comment: Then what's the problem? If you don't see any photo's, are they actually present on the server? Are the transferred to the client?

Comment: yeah. everything is in its place. And the only difference i see is the order the photos have in the array, on my pc is `galleryArray[0]="set1_1.jpg";` and on the server is `galleryArray[0]="set3_2.jpg";` which i think means nothing...

Comment: i also tried changing the header in the php to external javascript and still nothing...

Comment: I found another difference... At the end of the getPhotos.php the server automatically adds this:
`<!-- www.000webhost.com Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://analytics.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<noscript><a href="http://www.hosting24.com/"><img src="http://analytics.hosting24.com/count.php" alt="web hosting" /></a></noscript>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->`
Do you think it can cause any trouble???

Comment: ok! ifound that indeed the problem was those lines the server added. Ifound another host and works perfect! thank you all for your help. =)

Answer (score 1):

`;` after `returnImages()` is missing.

> This function (readdir) may return Boolean
>   FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to
>   FALSE, such as 0 or "". Please read
>   the section on Booleans for more
>   information. Use the === operator for
>   testing the return value of this
>   function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

So try to use `while(false != ($file = readdir($handle))){`
or `while(FALSE !== ($file = readdir($handle))){`

Comment: @Michael : I edited my answer. Let me know it helps you or not.

Comment: i changed it but now it shows some other errors which from what i get they have to do with file names and the extensions i say it should look for...

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is wrong, for one. You need to look at a regex tutorial, like [this one](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Comment: thanx for the advice. anything more i learn can only help me!